# dataweave 2 code works in one machine but not on the other (same O/S and Anypoint Studio version)

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am having problem with copying dataweave 2 code from one computer to another (both Windows 10 and Anypoint Studio 7, Mule Server 4.2.2 EE):

1. Export the jar file from the computer A
2. Import the same jar file to Anypoint Studio on computer B
3. Work/test on the code on machine B
4. Copy the transformer code (dataweave 2) from computer B to draft gmail
5. Open gmail on computer A and copy the code to the same transformer
6. There are errors - sometime just one, other times many errors

For example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var addr = payload.PersonInfo.AddressList.Address 
---
{
    Addresses: if (addr is Object)
        [addr] map ( address ) -> {
        Suburb: address.City
        }
    else 
        addr map ( address ) -> {
        Suburb: address.City
    }
}
```

the error points to the first map function: `'Invalid input "map (address) -> {\r\n\tSuburb: address.City\r\n\t ", expected Function Call (line 7 column 10):`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted into a Transform Message processor.  Most of the "errors" I see are warnings; you are being warned that there is auto-casting is being performed.  There are times false-positives you may get and its related to DataSense--did you try setting the input payload metadata?  Did you try running the server?  Moreover, provide us with sample input data and the desired output because I believe we can refactor your expression and make it a little better.

Comment: You have to share what is the input payload for this transformation, so we can try to rerproduce the error. Also you should paste the complete error message, not just a snippet that may be missing some important detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with OS - it is all data/payload and Dataweave script issues.
First - function map is for Array but what is shown in the error message is String with Object. Based on question script should expect to work with Array or String and should adjust to it.

Here is example how to do this 
https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/ChangeStringToJsonOnTheFly.html

Here is example how it could be. Play with it and change input to see how it behaves with different payload

```
%dw 2.0
var xAsObject=[{City:'AlbanyObject',State:'NY'},{City:'Seattle',State:'WA'}]
var xAsString='[{"City":"AlbanyString","State":"NY"},{"City":"Seattle","State":"WA"}]'
output application/json
var addr = xAsString
//var addr = xAsObject 
---
{
    Addresses: if (addr is Array)
        [addr] map ( address, index ) -> {
        Suburb: address.City
        }
    else if (addr is String )
        ( read ( ( addr default '' ), 'application/json' ) ) map ( address, index ) -> {
        Suburb: address.City
    }
    else {Suburb: 'Unknown'}
}
```

Possible outputs are (for String)

```
{
  "Addresses": [
    {
      "Suburb": "AlbanyString"
    },
    {
      "Suburb": "Seattle"
    }
  ]
}
```

and for Array

```
{
  "Addresses": [
    {
      "Suburb": [
        "AlbanyObject",
        "Seattle"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```